# Prevent browser caching of MVC partial pages as full pages (on back/forward)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, caching, partial-views

I have an iphone-style list-view system for navigation of a website that looks like this:

[image: How it should appear]

The URL is changed dynamically when a panel is loaded via AJAX and the same URL is placed in the browser address bar with puststate. This a allows a page refresh to reload the current page:

```
this.Historyjs.pushState({}, "", url);
```

To make this work the pages can return themselves as either a partial page, or a full page. The code to detect the difference is a base controller and looks like:

```
    public bool IsPartialPage
    {
        get
        {
            // ListViewer will strip out HTML from a full page if this occurs
            return Request.IsAjaxRequest() || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["partial"]);
        }
    }
```

An example controller action looks like this (note the Partial View cache expiry):

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=1)]
    public ActionResult ListViewerDocumentation()
    {
        if (!base.IsPartialPage)
        {
            ViewBag.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ListViewLayout.cshtml";
        }
        return PartialView();
    }
```

The problem I have is that when you navigate using the Browser's back and forward buttons, it will *occasionally* decide that a previously partial page is sufficient to become the entire page and does not make a call to the server (checked with Fiddler2) and so looks like this:

[image: How it appears after random Back/Forward]

Any suggestions on a method that will ensure back and forward navigation always pull back a full page and not from its cache of Ajax requests? Is it simply a matter of making the Ajax calls unique, or will the vanilla URL from the back/forward still match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the trick is to turn off caching **on the Ajax request** that pulls the partial pages, not on the server as that is never hit (the light suddenly came on after writing the above question):

```
   $.ajax(
            {
                cache: false,     // << Added this
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus: string, errorThrown: string)
                {
                    // On error (eg. "not found") empty out the display
                    THIS._removeContent();
                },
                success: function (data: string, textStatus: string, jqXHR)
                {
                    var $data = $(data);
                    THIS._insertContent($data, function ()
                    {
                    });
                }
            });
```

The cache false also apparently ensures the browser will not reuse the page on page back/forward operations.

Comment: Internet Explorer caches ajax requests by default, I'm glad you've figure this out.